# Double XML DOM getAttribute() Method + condition

Tags: javascript, html, xml, dom

I have an XML file that I want to pull some attributes from using JavaScript, but I only want it to return the attributes that appear if the attribute from a parent node matches a global variable which I have set in a previous script as part of the HTML page.

My XML file is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<directory name="weeks">
<directory name="week42">
<file name="one.pdf"/>
<file name="two.pdf"/>
<file name="three.pdf"/>
</directory>
<directory name="week43">
<file name="four.pdf"/>
<file name="five.pdf"/>
</directory>
</directory>
```

The idea is to list the 'name' attribute of the file nodes but only if the 'name' attribute from the directory parent node = a global variable 'week' that is set in an earlier script. The week variable will change based on the date (XML file will update as weeks get added & deleted), but for this example we can presume it has been set as **week42**

My code so far is below. It writes all of the 'name' attributes from all file nodes so my result is

```
one.pdf
two.pdf
three.pdf
four.pdf
five.pdf
```

--

```
function loadXMLDoc(weekslinks)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xhttp.open("GET","weeksdirlist.xml",false);
xhttp.send();
return xhttp.responseXML;
}  

xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("weeksdirlist.xml");
x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("file");

for (i=0;i<x.length;i++) 
{

var filename = x[i].getAttributeNode("name").nodeValue; //the nodefile is the filename
if (filename != "Thumbs.db")     
{
document.write(filename);
}
}
```

What I want is for my output to only return the 'name' attributes if the parent name attribute = my global variable which is week42. My output should therefore be

```
one.pdf
two.pdf
three.pdf
```

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.
Thanks, 
Ladders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we go....

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <script>
        text = "<directory name='weeks'><directory name='week42'>";
        text = text + "<file name='one.pdf'/><file name='two.pdf'/>";
        text = text + "<file name='three.pdf'/></directory>";
        text = text + "<directory name='week43'><file name='four.pdf'/>";
        text = text + "<file name='five.pdf'/></directory></directory>";
        if (window.DOMParser) {
            parser = new DOMParser();
            xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text, "text/xml");
        } else // Internet Explorer
        {
            xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
            xmlDoc.async = false;
            xmlDoc.loadXML(text);
        }
        var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('directory');

        var constant = 'week43';
        for (var i =0; i < x.length; i++) {
            var attrs = x[i].attributes;
            var k = attrs.getNamedItem("name").nodeValue;
            if (constant == k) {
                if (x[i].childNodes) {
                    document.write(k);
                    for ( var j = 0; j < x[i].childNodes.length; j++) {
                        var detail = x[i].childNodes[j];
                        var lattr = detail.attributes.getNamedItem("name").nodeValue;
                        document.write("<br>");
                        document.write(lattr);
                    }
                }
            }

        }


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

ouput will be

week43
four.pdf
five.pdf